# template no muestra los datos Vuejs

Tags: javascript, vue.js, ionic-framework

que tal tengo un problema utilizando Vue con ionic y es que hago una consulta para llenar un array, sin embargo a la hora de mostrarlo en el template no aparece, pero después de unas milésimas de segundos si lo imprime en consola

el código lo dejo aquí para que chequen

```
 template: `
    <div>

      {{array_tour.title}}

    </div>
      `,
  data() {

    return {

      array_tour: [],

    };
  },
  computed: {

  },
  created: function () {
    axios.get('https://jsonplaceholder.typicode.com/todos/1')
      .then(function (response) {
        this.array_tour = response.data
        console.log(this.array_tour)

      })
      .catch(function (error) {

      });
  },
```

Comment: Mira [ask] para que tu pregunta sea mejor recibida. También, aprovecha y haz el [tour] para entender mejor cómo funcionamos y de paso obtener tu primera [medalla](https://es.stackoverflow.com/help/badges)! Podrias mostrarnos que aparece en la consola?

Comment: Lo estas declarando como array y al momento de crearse no existe ese valor `array_tour.title`, puedes crear un objeto con datos vacíos

Comment: que tal, si recupero los datos de la petición, sin embargo después de un momento ya lo imprime en consola pero no en la vista, aquí esta lo que me trae [enlace](https://res.cloudinary.com/dycxesufw/image/upload/v1563991163/Captura_de_pantalla_94__LI_mybosx.jpg), también cree un jsfiddle por si gustan ver https://jsfiddle.net/Rhazhy/9q5e4bz7/8/

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Checa la variable _this, con esta tienes acceso al alcance de tus datos, y puedes usarla en la función de la respuesta. Un this en la función de respuesta no tendría el mismo alcance. 
Espero te sirva.

```js
var DetalleBuscador = {

  props: {
    url_ext: {
      type: String,
      required: true,
    }
  },

  template: `
    <div>
    hellosssss
      {{array_tour.title}}

    </div>
      `,
  data() {

    return {

      array_tour: [{
      
      }],

    };
  },
  computed: {

  },
  created: function () {
   var _this=this;
    axios.get('https://jsonplaceholder.typicode.com/todos/1')
      .then(function (response) {
        _this.array_tour = response.data
        console.log(_this.array_tour)

      })
      .catch(function (error) {

      });
  },
  methods: {

  },
  mounted: function () {
    
  },

};
Vue.customElement('detalle-buscador', DetalleBuscador);
```

Comment: gracias, si me funciono